# android studio not compatible with windows running

Tags: android

I have installed android Studio in windows 8 32-bit OS, but it shows an error(it is not compatible.), even i am running the Android studio in 32 bit mode.

```
Error:CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher
```

please suggest me what to do..

Thanks in advance.!

Answer (score 0):

I could suggest reinstalling JDK. I had exactly same error and found that my JDK installation was somehow broken, and reinstalling JDK solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. please uncheck the "use embedded JDK(recommended)"
2. and enter your jdk location manually (like C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.8.0_101)
3. Apply and ok

Answer (score -1):

1. First install your jdk
2. Then go to `file> project structure> sdk` location and in jdk location uncheck "use embedded jdk(recommended)
3. Type in box your jdk installation path